# Put a timer to the procedure of threading

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have about 60 timer in my program and them all take together.
now when them work together the timer get slow and not correct.so came in a conclusion that make a threading to the timer them get work. Hence I use threading but it actually gives errors.

how can i put them to threading?
Here is my code for the first timer, if anyone can explain how to do it in the first timer i can Duplicate.:
(Thank you all meet)

```
Private Sub sys_time_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Sys_time.Tick
    'TimeNow.Text = Date.Now.Date & " " & TimeOfDay
    TimeNow.Text = TimeOfDay.ToShortTimeString
    DATE1.Text = Date.Today
End Sub



Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    d1stats = 1
    If line1.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke Then
        Me.GroupBox1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 112, 34)
        If M1.Text >= 0 Then
            If S1.Text = 0 Then
                S1.Text = 59
                M1.Text = M1.Text - 1
            ElseIf S1.Text > 0 Then
                S1.Text = S1.Text - 1
            End If
        End If
        If M1.Text <= 0 AndAlso S1.Text <= 0 Then
            line1.BackColor = Color.Red
            My.Computer.Audio.Play("c:\beep-02.wav", AudioPlayMode.Background)
            If CheckBox1.Checked Then
                If pay_met1.Text = "מזומן" Then
                    MsgBox("D1" & Environment.NewLine & "המשלוח עבור רחוב" & " " & adress1.Text & " " & "מוכן" & Environment.NewLine & "שקית בצד" & Environment.NewLine & "מזומן")
                Else
                    MsgBox("D1" & Environment.NewLine & "המשלוח עבור רחוב" & " " & adress1.Text & " " & "מוכן" & Environment.NewLine & "שקית בצד")
                End If

            Else
                If pay_met1.Text = "מזומן" Then
                    MsgBox("D1" & Environment.NewLine & "המשלוח עבור רחוב" & " " & adress1.Text & " " & "מוכן" & Environment.NewLine & "מזומן")
                Else
                    MsgBox("D1" & Environment.NewLine & "המשלוח עבור רחוב" & " " & adress1.Text & " " & "מוכן")
                End If

            End If
        End If


    ElseIf line1.BackColor = Color.Yellow

        Me.GroupBox1.BackColor = Color.Brown

        If M1.Text >= 0 Then
            If S1.Text = 0 Then
                S1.Text = 59
                M1.Text = M1.Text - 1
            ElseIf S1.Text > 0 Then
                S1.Text = S1.Text - 1
            End If
        End If
        If M1.Text <= 0 AndAlso S1.Text <= 0 Then
            Timer1.Stop()
            niwstats = niwstats - 1
            Label5.Text = niwstats
            D1niwS = 0
            My.Computer.Audio.Play("c:\beep-01.wav", AudioPlayMode.Background)
            Timer1.Stop()
            MsgBox("יש לתזמן משלוח D1")
        End If



    ElseIf line1.BackColor = Color.Red
        Me.GroupBox1.BackColor = Color.Black
        Timer1.Interval = 1000
        Timer1.Start()
        S1.Text = S1.Text + 1
        If S1.Text >= 59 Then
            S1.Text = 0
            M1.Text = M1.Text + 1
        End If
        If M1.Text = 0 AndAlso S1.Text = timetoplaybeep Then
            My.Computer.Audio.Stop()
        End If
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: VS2015 doesnt do VB6 and that is not VB6 code.  I think you mean VB.NET.  Do all 60 timers (!?!) pop up MsgBoxes like that?

Comment: Why 60 timers? Can't you just combine all of them into one?

Comment: "the timer get slow and not currect"  You're assuming that the Timer will fire at exactly One second intervals, and are subtracting One second from the current "time".  The Timers are guaranteed to NOT fire before the specified interval and in fact will almost always fire after the interval (with varying amounts of delay), thus causing your times to "drift" significantly over time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually decrementing your countdown by 1 based on the Tick() event, actually setup a DateTime with your desired "target time" and CALCULATE the time remaining.  This will ensure an accurate countdown regardless of the Timer Interval.

This simple example shows a target time of 11:00 am:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private targetTime As DateTime
    Private scheduledTime As String = "11:00"
    Private WithEvents Tmr As New System.Windows.Forms.Timer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Tmr.Interval = 1000
        Tmr.Enabled = False
        SetTarget()
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetTarget()
        ' allow various time formats and attempt to parse the scheduled time: (with or without leading zeroes, allow am/pm or 24 hour format)
        Dim allowed() As String = {"h:mm", "hh:mm", "h:mm tt", "hh:mm tt", "H:mm", "HH:mm"}
        If DateTime.TryParseExact(scheduledTime, allowed, Nothing, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, targetTime) Then
            If targetTime < DateTime.Now Then
                ' we're already past the target time, schedule it for tomorrow at the same time:
                targetTime = targetTime.AddDays(1)
            End If
            Tmr.Start()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Tmr_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Tmr.Tick
        Dim ts As TimeSpan = targetTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now)
        If ts.TotalMilliseconds <= 0 Then
            Tmr.Stop()
            MessageBox.Show("Target Time Reached!")

            ' set it up again?
            SetTarget()
        Else
            ' display time remaining?
            Label1.Text = "Alarm Time: " & scheduledTime
            Label2.Text = "Current Date/Time: " & DateTime.Now
            Label3.Text = "Time Remaining: -" & ts.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")

            ' you could change colors or do something else in here based on the total amount of time left:
            ' make a decision based on "ts.TotalMilliseconds"?
            ' ... etc ...
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Example screenshot:

[image: Polling for a Target DateTime]